# Jquery Autocomplete return additional Dropdownlist value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am trying to consolidate the second function below into the autocomplete function.

They both at the momement work OK but I am trying to pass the value of a dropdownlist(DDL) back to the controller so that I can return results depending on which DDL is selected -

```
    // Autocomplete function 

$(function () {

    var createAutocomplete = function () {
        var $input = $(this);

        var options = {
            source: $input.attr("data-crs-autocomplete"),

            minLength: 2
        };
        $input.autocomplete(options);

    };

    $("input[data-crs-autocomplete]").each(createAutocomplete);

});



// For autocomplete by Section

$(function () {
    $("#SectionsID").on("change", function () {
        var value = $("#SectionsID").val();
        console.log(value)

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Records/Autocomplete',
            dataType: "json",
            data: { "selectedValue": value },
            })
    });
});
```

What would be the best way to do this?

I suspect something with var options of the autocomplete but unsure of the syntax...

Many thanks

Comment: Subsidiary note: if those instructions are in the same file, you only need one ready structure `$(function () {/* your code here */}`

Comment: Great thanks can you elaborate on how I would structure this?

Comment: Remove `});` before your 2nd comment, plus the `$(function () {` line right after it.